# Using Serilog in an app with several AppDomains

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, serilog

We have the following scenario where we encounter an issue with Serilog due to .NET's AppDomain isolation:

```
|App| --> |3rd| --> |Class| --> Log.Debug("...") --> [NOK]
    `-------------> |Class| --> Log.Debug("...") -->  [OK]

 (1)       (2)        (3)             (4)             (5)
```

1. We create a global `Logger` object in our app's `Main()` method and assign it to `Log.Logger`.
2. We invoke a third-party tool that *internally creates a new AppDomain*. (We have no control over this and cannot change this behavior.)
3. Instance objects of `Class` is created both within our app and from the third-party tool.
4. `Class` executes code for logging using Serilog's static `Log` class.
5. `Log.Logger` references the correctly configured `Logger` when accessed from the `Class` object created from our app, but is just set to a default `SilentLogger` in the `Class` object created via the third-party tool.

This, I guess, is the expected behavior since the two `Class` objects belongs to two different AppDomains and static variables are isolated to their own AppDomain.

Is there some way to work around this? Can we somehow make use of Serilog's convenient static `Log` class? Is there something else in the Serilog framework other than the `Log` class solving this kind of issue, that we might have missed? I found a similar issue in [#380](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/380) but without a final solution, as far as I could see.

We considered just creating a new `Logger` object in the new AppDomain. However, that means properties that we pushed to the `Logger` somewhere between 1-2 and 1-3 is not included in the new `Logger`'s log events.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you can't just pass around an instance of `Logger`. If you need to push properties onto that, why can't you use `LogContext.PushProperty` as described [in the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment)?

Comment: @mason I cannot pass an instance object of `Logger` into another AppDomain since the `Logger` class is not derived from `MarshalByRefObject`. (Nor is it marked with the `[Serializable]` attribute, though that would create a copy while passing the instance object.) To my understanding these are the two options one have to pass .NET objects across AppDomains. If I instead would create a new `Logger` object inside the second AppDomain any property pushed using `LogContext.PushProperty()` in e.g. the first AppDomain would only be pushed to the `Logger` object inside that particular domain.